# Why the touch event on the child of my ViewGroup does'nt work?

Tags: android, view, touch-event, viewgroup

Here is my code - PadsGrid is a ViewGroup -  :

```
public class Emc_PadControllerActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final PadsGrid pg = new PadsGrid(this, 8, 5, PadType.SMALL);
        for (int i=0;i<pg.getChildCount();i++){
            final PadController pc;
            pc=(View) pg.getChildAt(i);
            pc.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                    pc.onTouch(arg0,arg1);
                    return true;
                }});;
        }

        setContentView(pg);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        v.onTouchEvent(event);
        return false;
    }
}
```

In this, the onTouch Event of my views is'nt call why I touch them, why ?

Answer (score 1):

You want to set your onTouchlistener to `Emc_PadControllerActivity.this` instead of using the anonymous inner class as such:

```
   pc.setOnTouchListener(Emc_PadControllerActivity.this)
```

this will call your onTouch() in the main class.  Here you can determine which view was clicked and act accordingly.

Check out my earlier [question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108918/how-do-i-reference-the-main-activitys-onclick-from-within-the-onclick-menthod-o)

Comment: Ok, but I wanted the views directly cath the onTouchEvent.
Because this way is faster and easier to treat multitouch events !

Comment: In that case you should be able to `pc.setOnTouchListener(pc.onTouch());`...  I am assuming the pc class has an onTouch() method.

Comment: Yes of course, but how to pass the two arguments : Event and View to the onTocuh method ?

Comment: I've tried your solution by adding this method in my PadController :
 public OnTouchListener onTouch() {
  Log.d("PadController","Touched!");
  return null;
 }
But nothing happened !

Comment: I am certain that is done automatically... see the [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html](OnTouchListener Interface docs.)  Your control implements the interface and the method, the framework does the rest.